# Fit this data to a model in mathematica

Tags: fitting

I need to find a distribution or a model to fit this data set in Mathematica

```
data3 = {{1, 1.3}, {2, 2.4}, {3, 3.8}, {4, 4.8}, {5, 5.6}, {6, 
6.3}, {7, 6.9}, {8, 7.3}, {9, 7.6}, {10, 7.8}, {15, 8.25}, {18, 
8.3}, {20, 8.1}, {22.5, 7.6}, {30, 6.2}, {40, 3.9}, {50, 
1.8}, {60, 0.7}};
```

the data is from a resonance circuit

Comment: What have you tried already? More information about the data would also be extremely useful.

Comment: FindFormula is supposed to help you get started by suggesting some models, but I don's find the suggestions useful. Try with `NonlinearModelFit[data3, 
 a x/Exp[b x] + c x + d, {{a, 2}, {b, .1}, {c, 0}, d}, x]`

Comment: What does the data represent? It's generally a bad idea to try to fit to data without having some prior knowledge of what physical process generates the data and what fit is likely to be correct. Otherwise, the only thing you have to go on is the error in the fit and gut feeling. You can always get a perfect fit with 18 data points using $a_1 x^{17} + a_2 x^{16} + a_3 x^{15} + ... + a_{17} x + a_{18}$. If there's really no further detail, then I suppose you just have to guess, and @GustavoDelfino 's guess seems as good as any.

Comment: Here is my standard comment about this:  Are you fitting a regression curve that happens to have a similar shape as a probability distribution or does the data represent a sample from a random variable and the associated numbers (`data3[[All,2]`) are some sort of relative frequencies?  If the latter, you need the actual counts rather than relative frequencies.  Also, you seem to have "binned" the data and you need the raw data. In short, you should give a brief explanation as to how the data was collected and what it represents.

Comment: rami mahmoud, if you are the same person as Rami1234, I recommend that you merge your accounts, so that you have less difficulty editing your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

here is a distribution that is very close to your data

```
data = Rest[4.1 Table[PDF[BetaDistribution[1.7,3.5],k],{k,0,1,1/74}]]   

ListPlot@data
```

[image]

here is the comparison between the two sets when selecting the same points

```
data = Table[{n, 
Rest[4.1 Table[
   PDF[BetaDistribution[1.7, 3.5], k], {k, 0, 1, 
    1/74}]][[n]]}, {n, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 18, 20,
 22, 30, 40, 50, 60}}]

data3 = {{1, 1.3}, {2, 2.4}, {3, 3.8}, {4, 4.8}, {5, 5.6}, {6, 
6.3}, {7, 6.9}, {8, 7.3}, {9, 7.6}, {10, 7.8}, {15, 8.25}, {18, 
8.3}, {20, 8.1}, {22.5, 7.6}, {30, 6.2}, {40, 3.9}, {50, 1.8}, {60,
0.7}}    

ListPlot[{data, data3}]
```

[image]

Comment: What estimation method did you use?  If this turns out to be a regression problem rather than a fitting a distribution problem, then something like `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data3, a (x/100)^b (1 - (x/100))^c, {a, b, c},
    x];` might be better.

Comment: This method is too complicated for me to explain in the comment section. But it returns better results than FindFormula and similar functions.